# XML Serialization and Empty Constructors

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following class that allows me to serialize objects in my program:

```
import java.beans.XMLDecoder;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Persistor<T> {

    private T data;

    public void save(T data, String file) {

        try {

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
            encoder.writeObject(data);
            encoder.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("File not found");

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "finally" })
    public T read(String file) {

        try {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(fis);
            data = (T)decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("File not found");

        } finally {

            return data;

        }

    }

}
```

The thing is that I have my bussiness logic package with classes like student and it seems like I need to have an empty constructor `public Student() {}` to get the program working:

```
package logic;

public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    } public Student() {} // empty constructor

    public String getName() {

        return name;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }

    public String toString() {

        return name;

    }

}
```

If I take out the empty constructor, the following exceptions appear on the console:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: logic.Student
Continuing ...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The outer element does not return value
Continuing ...
```

Is there any way to fix this stuff, I mean by not having the empty constructor? Because I have like 7 more classes where everyone needs to have it's own empty constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ConstructorProperties` annotation

```
public class Student {
    private String name;

    @ConstructorProperties("name")
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

test

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Student s1 = new Student("Jon");
         XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream("xxx"));
         encoder.writeObject(s1);
         encoder.close();

         XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream("xxx"));
         Student s2 = (Student)decoder.readObject();
         decoder.close();
         System.out.println(s2);
    }
}
```

output

```
test.Student@e3fd79
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried using this and I keep getting the same exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I've recently tried yours and it works fine. Still don't know why mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to deserialize a bean.
The way most serialization frameworks including XMLEncoder/Decoder go about this is by instantiating a default no-arg constructor and then reflectively calling the getters or setters for each one of the member objects.

The documentation seems to support this...

XMLDecoder [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html):

> The XMLDecoder class is used to read XML documents created using the
>   XMLEncoder and is used just like the ObjectInputStream.

ObjectInputStream [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

> Reading an object is analogous to running the constructors of a new
>   object. Memory is allocated for the object and initialized to zero
>   (NULL). No-arg constructors are invoked for the non-serializable
>   classes and then the fields of the serializable classes are restored
>   from the stream starting with the serializable class closest to
>   java.lang.object and finishing with the object's most specific class.
>
> ...
>
> Serialization does not read or assign values to the fields of any
>   object that does not implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
>   Subclasses of Objects that are not serializable can be serializable.
>   In this case the non-serializable class must have a no-arg constructor
>   to allow its fields to be initialized. In this case it is the
>   responsibility of the subclass to save and restore the state of the
>   non-serializable class. It is frequently the case that the fields of
>   that class are accessible (public, package, or protected) or that
>   there are get and set methods that can be used to restore the state.

From the documentation you can see that your options are either to implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) or add the no-arg constructor and keep getters and setters for all your fields.